# PWM input to raspberry pi 4B

Tags: pi-4, sensor, pwm

I want to read PWM output signal which I got from a sensor. Is there any way to give PWM signals as input to Raspberry pi 4B?

Comment: You need to clarify the characteristics of the PWM you want to read.

Answer (score 0):

PWM is a digital signal.

You could (at least in principle) monitor to detect the proportion of time it is HIGH.

If I wanted to do this I would write code to detect rising and falling edges and times.

I am unaware of any existing code although Joan's [DHT](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/DHT.py) temperature humidity code would provide an excellent starting point.